# Garudi Paravidya

Tags: vishnu, puranas, garuda-purana

नमस्कार  Can someone kindly enlighten me on the **Garudi Paravidya** that appears in the **Garuda Purana**. I have heard it elsewhere and more curious to know more about it in detail. धन्यवाद